# Can I make a downloadable .exe app for my game if I make it in HTML5?

Tags: html5, single-player

I was going to make a MMORPG in HTML5 and javascript but I think I'm going to make a singelplayer first after all.. It would be nice to make the game in html5 anyway so the transition to making an mmorpg in future will be smoother.

But I would like the game to be downloadable app which is then installed like most games are.. Not a unzippable container containing a .js file.. I also want to be able to put the game up on steam.

I also don't really want the source code to be open for anyone to see if I let them download the game in a zip file where the .js and .html files are inside.

Is there a way of accomplishing this?
Otherwise I will probably have to use some other language for making my game in some framework/engine like unity/xna/game maker but like I said I would prefer just using html5 and javascript with my own custom code.

Comment: Maybe there are wrappers like that, but even then I suppose that they could relatively easily be decompiled again. It's not really meant for this use case, but maybe you could build something like that yourself with [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) and some C++ or .NET code.

Ultimately, if you worry about people seeing the source, HTML5 is probably not a good choice. But if the end goal is an MMORPG, all important logic will (or at least _should_) be done serverside anyway, so it won't be much of an issue anymore.

Comment: There may be some information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504651/pack-an-html5-app-and-deploy-it-on-the-desktop

Comment: If someone wants your code, they'll get it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to make a game in C++.

Comment: Quit worrying about people stealing your code at least until you start writing anything that is actually stealworthy, it doesn't sound like you are there yet.

Comment: As I understand there's no good way to accomplish what I asked for then.. I will have to use unity then.. thanks to those that answered the question.. wish I could give minus rep to the troll ebusiness.

Comment: @Krymmt I'm not trolling, I'm just being a little more honest than most people would usually dare. There is nothing wrong about being a beginner, but it means that your focus should be on learning the basic craft, rather than hunting for shoddy DRM solutions.

Comment: You make it sound like it's hard to make a singleplayer game.. It really just is time consuming thats all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). One example of this in the real world is a game called [Lava Blade](http://www.lavablade.com/) which is available on both Windows and Mac.